# Beginner - C Program only prints the last row of a 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I have written a simple C program which inputs and prints the results of 2 multi-dimensional arrays, matrix A and matrix B.
However, for some reason, when I try to print the results of the matrices, it only repeatedly returns the last row of each matrix.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFGBZ.png

`````
   char input;
   int row, col;
   int matrixA[row][col];
   int matrixB[row][col];
   int matrixResult[row][col];
   
   printf("Addition, Subtraction, and Multiplication of Matrices\n");
   printf("Set row size of matrices A and B: ");
   scanf("%d", &row);
   printf("Set column size of matrices A and B: ");
   scanf("%d", &col);
   int i, j;
   for(i=0; i<row; i++) {
     for(j=0;j<col;j++) {
        printf("Enter value for matrixA[%d][%d]:", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &matrixA[i][j]);
     }
  }
   for(i=0; i<row; i++) {
     for(j=0;j<col;j++) {
        printf("Enter value for matrixB[%d][%d]:", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &matrixB[i][j]);
     }
  }
   printf("\n\n");
   
   printf("Row size of Matrices A and B is: %d\n", row);
   printf("Column size of Matrices A and B is: %d\n\n", col);
   
   printf("Elements of matrix A:\n");
  for(i=0; i<row; i++){
  for(j=0;j<col;j++){
        printf("The value of matrixA[%d][%d] is %d\t", i ,j , matrixA[i][j]);
        if(j==col-1){
           printf("\n");
        }
     }
  }
  
  printf("Elements of matrix B:\n");
  for(i=0; i<row; i++) {
     for(j=0;j<col;j++) {
        printf("%d ", matrixB[i][j]);
        if(j==col-1){
        printf("\n");
        }
     }
  }

   
   return 0;
   }````


I am still a beginner to the C language and programming in general, so any help to my questions would be much appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: SOLVED
Thank you so much Vlad from Moscow and M Oehm for the help!
I defined the constant variables ROW and COL (not the same int row and col in the main function) with a maximum number of 6. I also initialized int row and col to 0. The beginning of the code should look like this now:
   ````
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #define ROW 6
   #define COL 6

   int main() {
   int row = 0, col = 0;
   int matrixA[ROW][COL];
   int matrixB[ROW][COL];

   }
   ````
`````

Comment: These declarations  int row, col;
    int matrixA[row][col];
    int matrixB[row][col];
    int matrixResult[row][col]; result in undefined behavior because the variables row and col were not initialized.

Comment: C programs are sequential. At the time you define your 2d arrays, neither of the dimensions `col` or `row` has a meaningful value. Defer their definition until after asking the user for the dimensions. Alternatively, make the matrices "big enough", say 10×10, and enforce that the user input for `col` and `row` is positive, but at most 10.

Comment: Thank you Vlad and M. Will work on your suggestions.

Comment: I used the code:
```#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"matrix.h"
#define ROW 6
#define COL 6

int main() {
 char input;
 int row = 0, col = 0;
 int matrixA[ROW][COL];
 int matrixB[ROW][COL];
```
Everything works fine now! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your matrices before reading their actual sizes. There is no way of knowing what is inside row and col before you actually read them, so declaring anything based off them would result in undefined behaviour.

Try this: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/EZlQhvVO9V.